Python Pyside6 QtableView Data model display data in locale format
I have a problem displaying data coming from QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel().
here one function I use to build the data model:
# FUNCTION IN DATABASE MODULE
def incomeViewData(self):
    """
    data model for income table
    """
    self.model.setTable("income")
    """
    set relation to the category, cycle and fix to show the name instead the id
    """
    self.model.setRelation(3, QtSql.QSqlRelation("inc_category", "inc_cat_id", "inc_cat_name"))
    self.model.setRelation(4, QtSql.QSqlRelation("cycle", "cyc_id", "cycle_name"))
    self.model.setRelation(5, QtSql.QSqlRelation("var_fix", "var_id", "value"))
    """
    set the ability to have a combobox for the category when double clicked in the cell
    """
    # self.tbl_income.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate())
    
    # FORMAT HEADER
    self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
    self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Datum")
    self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Betrag")
    self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Kategorie")
    self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Turnus")
    self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "Fix")
    self.model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "Bemerkung")
    self.model.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    return self.model # RETURNS MODEL TO CALLING FUNCTION

# CALLING FUNCTION
def incomeView(self):
    # data model for income table
    mod_income = dbc().incomeViewData()
    mod_income.select()
    
    self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.setModel(mod_income)
    self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.setColumnHidden(0, True)
    for i in range(mod_income.columnCount()):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912374/how-to-set-a-pyside6-qtablewidget-column-width-to-15pt
        self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(175)
        self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(i, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

and here is my result:

How can I set the date and amount to be displayed in local format like date 14.02.2023 and amunt 2.341,64?

What you see is the current locale you're using (or, to be precise, what Qt detects from the system). You could consider to change the default locale (QLocale.setDefault()) with one you know uses the dot for date/thousand separators and comma for decimals. Alternatively, use a custom delegate and override displayText().

Hi, I set already the QLocale to QLocale.system() but it does not affect this tableview.  Where should I set the displayText()? I’m sorry but I do not have any experience in using custom delegates. It would be nice if you could share some experience and show some example that could help solve this problem. Thanks!

On Windows/Mac QLocale should use the formats set for the system by default. I assume that you're using a German locale (probably de_DE) which does by default use dots for date/groups and comma for decimal point (at least on Linux), unless the system is configured differently. What is the output of QLocale.system().uiLanguages(), QLocale.system().dateFormat(QLocale.FormatType.ShortFormat) and QLocale.system().decimalPoint()?

The output is: UI Lang:  ['de-DE', 'de-Latn-DE', 'de'] Date format:  dd.MM.yyyy DEzimal: ,
This is getting out the right formats but the PySide Widgets do not get it right seems so

Or could it be the case that the Sqlite DB gives the wrong "information" to the TableView? I set the fields as DATE and DOUBLE (10,2)

I let also get out the locale of the TableView and got this result.
<PySide6.QtCore.QLocale(German, Latin, Germany) at 0x00000246F8889900>
So I think it could be realy some issue with the database.

Are those values stored as strings on the database? Because I assumed that you were actually using date and numeric objects. If they're strings, then the locale won't do any good, because strings are reported verbatim. Do some research about using delegates, you could subclass QStyledItemDelegate and override displayText(), then return a different result based on the content (for instance, using a regex).

The date is a string (Sqllite have just text) but the amount is a number. I tryed to store it as QDate or python date but this was also not the solution.

Then the problem is how those strings are created/entered in the database. If you have control over data insertion, then do that at that level, you cannot expect Qt to magically guess data types from a string and parse it for you: a string is a string, the fact that you give it a meaning as a date or something else is pointless. If you cannot control insertion, then you should at least assume the possible content of each column you know of, therefore replace it based on your needs: if you know that a column contains yyyy-MM-dd formatted dates, then replace - with / in the delegate.

Note that we can only give help based on what provided. Until your comment above, we didn't know you were using SQLite, and most SQL databases are strictly typed (providing date/time types) so we could have only assumed that you were using proper date values. For future reference, always provide appropriate context and a proper [mre] (your code is quite partial, forcing us to make assumptions). That said, SQLite certainly has not "just text": it also provides integers, floats and "data blobs", meaning that virtually anything (including binary data, with byte arrays) can be stored.

Of course you are right! Sorry. You helped me very good and I could solve the problem with the date. Only the amount is not fixed yet. I store the data in a field that is in SQLite REAL. If you have any suggestions it would be great.

If you're referring to your previous edit on your answer, the delegate is not the problem, how you create it is: as the documentation about setItemDelegate functions says, the view does not take ownership of the delegate, and since there's no persistent reference to that instance, that's a problem. At the very least, you should make an instance attribute for each delegate (eg: self.dateDelegate), but, in reality, creating it with a proper parent is more appropriate. Add a parent argument to the init and use it in in the super __init__, then create it with the table as parent.

I think I found sometihing that my help me to get the results I want to have.
https://overthere.co.uk/2012/07/29/using-qstyleditemdelegate-on-a-qtableview/
class DateFormatDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, date_format):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self)        
        self.date_format = date_format

def displayText(self, value, locale):
    # ORIGINAL RETURN
    # return value.toDate().toString(self.date_format)
    
    # MY RETURN
    return QDate.fromString(value, "yyyy-MM-dd").toString("dd.MM.yyyy")

then in my calling function I added this line
self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, DateFormatDelegate('dd.MM.yyyy'))


Thanks @musicamante for geting me the right direction for research :)
