Python Pyside6 QtableView Data model delete record
I have a question about deleting records from a database. The data is displayed in a QTableView and is sorted by date. The problem is that if I use the current index of the QTableView as a "row", the wrong records are deleted because they are sorted differently in the database. For example, I click on the first row and get a 0 as the index, but another record is stored under index 0 in the database. How do I get it to click on a record in the QTableView and have it deleted?
I use Pyside6 and Sqlite. For database manipulation like loading, deleting, sorting, inserting etc. I use QtSql and QSqlRelationalTableModel. I don't use SQL or QtSql SQL queries, I rely on the data model.
Thanks!
WINDOW
# IMPORT PACKAGES AND MODULES
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import sys
import os
import datetime

# IMPORT DATABASE MODULES
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from test_database import DataBaseConnector as dbc
from PySide6 import QtSql
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow

# IMPORT DELEGATE FOR CONVERTING DISPLAYED DATE
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from delegate import DateFormatDelegate, AlignDelegate

# IMPORT QT CORE
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from qt_core import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # SETUP MAIN WINDOw
        # Load widgets from "gui\uis\main_window\ui_main.py"
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.incomeViewSearch()
        self.ui.pb_inc_del.clicked.connect(self.deleteIncome)

    # MESSAGES
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def okayMessage(self, text):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Datensatz",
                                f"{text}")

    def failMessage(self, text):
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Datensatzfehler", f"{text}")

    # DATA LOAD FILTERED INCOME
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def incomeViewSearch(self):
        # data model for income table
        mod_income_search = None
        # VARIABLES FOR THE FILTER SO NOT GET SOOOOO LONG :)


        # CHECK IF THE FILTER TOGGLE IS CHECKED

        start_date = "1752-09-14"  # VERY FIRST DATE
        end_date = "9999-12-31"  # VERY LAST DATE
        # RUN THE FILTER WITHOUT DATE SET FROM VERY PAST TO INFINITY
        mod_income_search = dbc().incomeViewSearch(filter_begin=start_date, filter_end=end_date,)

        mod_income_search.select()
        self.ui.tbl_income.setModel(mod_income_search)
        self.ui.tbl_income.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, DateFormatDelegate('dd.MM.yyyy'))
        # self.ui.load_pages.tbl_income.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, AlignDelegate())
        self.ui.tbl_income.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        for i in range(mod_income_search.columnCount()):
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912374/how-to-set-a-pyside6-qtablewidget-column-width-to-15pt
            self.ui.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(175)
            self.ui.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(i, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
            self.ui.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    # DELETE INCOME
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def deleteIncome(self):
        rows = sorted(set(index.row() for index in
                          self.ui.tbl_income.selectedIndexes()))

        print(rows)
        for row in rows:
            print(f'Row {row} is selected')
            dbc().deleteIncome(row)


# SETTINGS WHEN TO START
# Set the initial class and also additional parameters of the "QApplication" class
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # APPLICATION
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    # EXEC APP
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    sys.exit(app.exec())

DATABASE
import os
import sys
import datetime

############### import ##################
from PySide6 import QtSql, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class DataBaseConnector:

    # INIT
    # //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def __init__(self):
        self.database = None
        self.model = None
        self.dbdriver = "QSQLITE"
        self.dbname = "test_expense.db"
        self.connect_db()

    """
    connects to the database need two arguments database driver and database name
    """

    # CONNECT DATABASE
    # //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def connect_db(self):
        """

        :return: DB Connection
        """
        if not os.path.isfile(self.dbname):
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Fehler", "Keine Datenbankverbindung!\n"
                                                 f"Bitte prüfen, ob die Datenbank {self.dbname} vorhanden ist.")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            self.database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase(self.dbdriver)
            self.database.setDatabaseName(self.dbname)
            self.model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
            # print(self.dbname)
            return True

    # CREATE INCOME MODEL
    # //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def incomeViewSearch(self, filter_begin="", filter_end=""):
        """

        @param filter_begin:
        @param filter_end:
        @param filter_amount:
        @param filter_category:
        @param filter_note_txt:
        @return:
        """
        # data model for income table
        self.model.setTable("income")
        # if filter_begin:
        #     """
        #     This is an other way but it does not work
        #     """

        """
        # This is working but no relations and delegates
        self.mod_income_search.setQuery("SELECT * FROM income where inc_date >= '" + map + "' and inc_date <= '" + map2 + "'")
        print(self.mod_income_search.index(0, 1).data())
        """

        # SET RELATION TO THE CATEGORY, CYCLE AND FIX TO SHOW THE NAME INSTEAD THE ID
        self.model.setRelation(3, QtSql.QSqlRelation("inc_category", "inc_cat_id", "inc_cat_name"))
        self.model.setRelation(4, QtSql.QSqlRelation("cycle", "cyc_id", "cycle_name"))
        self.model.setRelation(5, QtSql.QSqlRelation("var_fix", "var_id", "value"))
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Datum")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Betrag in €")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Kategorie")
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Turnus")
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "Fix")
        self.model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "Bemerkung")
        self.model.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        # SET FILTER FOR DATA
        self.model.setFilter(f"(date(inc_date) BETWEEN '{filter_begin}' AND '{filter_end}') ")
        return self.model  # .select()

    # DELETE INCOME
    # //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def deleteIncome(self, row):
        self.model.setTable("income")
        try:
            # DELETE RECORD
            self.model.select()
            self.model.removeRow(row)
            print("Daten gelöscht")
            self.model.select()
            self.database.close()

        except QtSql.QSqlError.ErrorType.value as e:
            print("GOES WRONG")

UI
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'test_mainOuWzOQ.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.8.0
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QFrame, QHeaderView,
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QStatusBar,
    QTableView, QWidget)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.tbl_income = QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tbl_income.setObjectName(u"tbl_income")
        self.tbl_income.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 781, 501))
        self.tbl_income.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Arial\";")
        self.tbl_income.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Shadow.Plain)
        self.tbl_income.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tbl_income.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.SingleSelection)
        self.tbl_income.setTextElideMode(Qt.TextElideMode.ElideLeft)
        self.tbl_income.setShowGrid(False)
        self.tbl_income.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tbl_income.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tbl_income.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tbl_income.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(10)
        self.tbl_income.verticalHeader().setProperty(u"showSortIndicator", True)
        self.pb_inc_del = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_inc_del.setObjectName(u"pb_inc_del")
        self.pb_inc_del.setGeometry(QRect(260, 520, 281, 51))
        self.pb_inc_del.setStyleSheet(u"font: 18pt \"Arial\";\n"
"color: rgb(0, 84, 147);\n"
"background-color: rgb(122, 129, 255);\n"
"border-radius:8px;")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pb_inc_del.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"DELETE", None))
    # retranslateUi



Databases don't really have the concept of "row index" (except for the row id, which may not always be consistent, though). If you see the same record in a different row in the database and the view, then either of those (or both) are displaying data using internal sorting. QSqlTableModel is perfectly able to remove the correct record based on the logical index it's given, as long as you're correctly using removeRows() and you didn't do anything wrong (like changing the query). As already suggested in your previous post, we can only help you if you provide an appropriate [mre].


The problem is that if I use the current index of the QTableView as a "row", the wrong records are deleted because they are sorted differently in the database.

In short you should NEVER assume that the nth object in the UI equates to the nth row in the database, it RARELY, IF EVER, does.
The rows in a database aren't stored as sorted, they are just stored, when rows are processed (searched) they are processed according to whatever index is deemed most suitable. This includes retrieval which may be according to the ORDER BY clause (which may or may not be specified, in the case of not being specified then according to what the query optimiser decides).
Often the rowid or an alias thereof is the typical index. An alias of the rowid will exist/be created when:-

A single column is the PRIMARY KEY, AND
that column has a type that is specifically INTEGER (not INT or any other type who's affinity is resolved as INTEGER e.g. BIGINT).
This includes when the column has the AUTOINCREMENT constraint.

For a column that is an alias of the rowid AND if no value or a value of NULL is assigned when inserting the row, then the value will be generated by SQLite. Such a value will be 1 for the very first row or it will be 1 greater than:-

the highest existing value for the 'rowid 'column in the table, or in the case of using AUTOINCREMENT,

the higher value of the maximum existing 'rowid' in the table and the highest recorded (ever existing) value used for the rowid.



In the case of this rowid then the value, unless forced will never be 0.
As such your click is very likely using the index (position) within the list presented to the UI which will very likely not be the rowid or alias thereof and thus if the UI index value is used it will not deleted the anticipated row but will either delete another row or not delete to any row.
What you should be doing is extract the value or values from the data (object) at the clicked UI index that can be used to uniquely identify the row in question. The DELETE or UPDATE should then use the value or values in the WHERE clause.
Perhaps consider the following demonstration using an SQLite tool:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t 
    (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, /* will be an alias of the rowid*/
    d1 whatever, /* type affinity resolved SQLite (which will be NUMERIC) */
    d2 TEXT
    )
;
/* Insert some data where the rowid (id is an alias of the rowid)*/
INSERT INTO t (d1,d2) VALUES 
    ('d1-01','d2-01'),('d1-02','d2-02'),('d1-03','d2-03')
;
/* insert some additional data BUT this time specifying a value for the rowid alias (id column)*/
INSERT INTO t (id,d1,d2) VALUES 
    (10,'d1-04','d2-04'),(null,'d1-05','d2-05'),
    (-100 /* yes rowid can be negative*/,'d1-06','d2-06'),
    (null,'d1-07','d2-07') ,
    (0,'d1-08','d2-08') /* Only way to have an id of 0 is to force 0 by specifying it (SQLite will not generate a value of 0)*/
    /* .... */
;
/* SELECT DATA however SQLite determines (probably according to the primary key)*/
/* NOTE that even though -100 id value was inserted as the 6th row is is the 1st row selected */
SELECT * FROM t;
/* Data selected according to the ORDER BY extracts in a different order */
/* NOTE that due to the d1 column adhereing to the sequence of insertion that the order is therefore now according to the insertion*/
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY d1;
/* clean up the demo environment*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;

Now consider the two outputs (SELECTS).
The 1st extracting:-


assuming the image is what the UI presents then:-

If this were to drive the UI then the first row, UI index 0, will have an id of -100 that uniquely identifies the row. If the UI index 0 where used to drive the update then the data displaying -100 d1-06 and d2-06 would in fact delete the row that has data 0 d1-08 and d2-08.

HOWEVER by extracting the value of the id from the object at index 0 (i.e. -100) and using that in the DELETE's WHERE clause WILL result in the appropriate row being deleted.


If UI index 5 were used ('10 d1-01 and d204') then as there is no row that has an id of 5, no row would be deleted.


The 2nd extracting:-


If this were to drive the UI then the first row, UI index 0, will have an id of -1 that uniquely identifies the row. If the UI index 0 where used to drive the update then the data displaying 1 d1-01 and d2-01 would in fact delete the row that has data 0 d1-08 and d2-08.

If UI index 5 were used ('-100 d1-06 and d2-06') then as there is no row that has an id of 5, no row would be deleted.



The OP is using the Qt framework, which provides SQL abstraction layers: it may not be always perfect, but trying to access the database from outside of that implementation is discouraged. As already written in my comment to the post, Qt's item model/view and SQL implementation is perfectly capable of keeping track of visual rows considering the actual context of records and therefore remove appropriate "rows" based on the visual index of the displayed model. There's still the possibility of bugs or wrong API calls, but we cannot know that for certain until they provide a MRE.

I think I got the solution :)
Please give me a response if it is a bette way to do it.
Here is the delete method:
    # DELETE INCOME
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def deleteIncome(self):
        
        model = self.ui.tbl_income.model()
        rows = sorted(set(index.row() for index in
                          self.ui.tbl_income.selectedIndexes()))

        print(rows)
        for row in rows:
            print(f'Row {row} is selected')
            del_row = model.index(row, 0).row() #
            model.removeRow(del_row)
            # THIS IS NOT WORKING - DELETES THE WRONG RECORDS
            # dbc().deleteIncome(del_row)
        self.incomeViewSearch()


deleteIncome() does not delete the wrong records, you are assuming the wrong record indexes: when you call incomeViewSearch() you also apply sorting to the model , but in deleteIncome() of DataBaseConnector you are not, which is exactly what I explained in my comment; the row 0 of the view was not the row 0 of the model on which you call removeRow, because they are different model. It also makes very little sense to continuously create a dbc instance (which also creates a new model every time): not only it's prone to implementation bugs like yours, but it's also very ineffective.

That DataBaseConnector class should at the very least implement a singleton mechanism, and possibly as a QSqlTableModel (or QSqlRelationalTableModel) subclass. In that way you don't waste memory and resources by forcibly creating new models (that are being garbage collected every time) and resetting the model in use in the tab. Calling again incomeViewSearch is also pointless for the same reason: just ensure you submit changes after row deletion. Finally, proper deletion must use a reverse order, otherwise it will skip indexes.

Thank you very much for the deep explanation! As I mentioned I'm not a proffesional programer and just begun to learn to work with PySide6 Sql and its data model. I wanted to keep the view and the data modules apart and just pull the data I need from the database to display it on the form. The form has the function to add, display, edit and delete data. So I have to load the incomeViewSearch() on enty, on adding, edit and delete the data. Or is there an better way to do it?
THANK YOU

There is nothing wrong in separating the view from the data model, the problem is how you create, access and update the model. As written, there is no point in continuously create new models: you seem to use only one view, therefore just ensure that every change is properly submitted to the model; calling incomeViewSearch of DataBaseConnector every time is inefficient and pointless, as Qt is perfectly capable of updating the view when the model changes, including sorting or filtering (as long as done appropriately). Even if you needed more views with different sorting or filtering, you could »

» still use the unique instance of the model of a source of one or many QSortFilterProxyModel (including subclasses, if you want custom filtering), and eventually create different instances based on the same source and set on different views. In this way, there will always be one reference model (the one actually connected to the database) and all views will be automatically updated accordingly whenever any change is applied. Unrelated note: you should always use layout managers, even in Designer.

Thank you very much. It would help me a lot if you could give me an example of how to do it correctly. Preferably using my example code. I would like to learn the stuff, but there are very few resources and most of them deal with SQL rather than the data model. I have looked at some examples from the QT documentation and I don't understand most of them. It's frustrating.

Unfortunately, I cannot answer this post with what you ask, because it would be off topic to the matter at hand. The Qt item/model framework is quite robust as it's extensive, and requires a lot of patience and experience (therefore, time) to really understand it. The Qt docs are a good start, as long as you diligently study them, starting from the model/view introduction. As a beginner, it would be natural to try to skip steps in order to get what you want, and that's one way to learn things (not a waste of time, but quite inefficient).

My suggestion is to take your time and be really patient in learning the whole model/view approach (and I'm talking about the general concept, not only the Qt one), which, to some extent, is not that different to understanding the relation between objects, their usage and purpose, and therefore when/why/how objects should be created or used. In your case, the main issue really had little to do with Qt, but with comprehension about object structures and lifespans (creating multiple objects and instantly discarding them, believing they are the same and result in identical/consistent behavior).

Start by carefully thinking about what happens whenever you do dbc() (which returns a completely different object every time, no matter if it seems "identical"), and do proper research about object identity: even doing dbc() == dbc() would return False, which is a quite important hint about what you tried to achieve (even though their original model might have same contents). That said, be aware, not being a professional isn't that relevant; programming is not even my day job: I'm a musician, I mostly code for fun.
